# Weird Apache HTTPD 403 Error

Tags: permissions, httpd, inode

So I'm having this really weird problem that I've worked around, but I don't understand why it's happening.

I have a file I'm hosting via httpd. Below is a list of things I've tested/thought of to try to explain what's going on:

- When I try to access the file, I get a 403.
- When I do an Index listing in Apache, it doesn't even show up but other files do
- Other files in the directory that are 644 show up in Indexes and I can access them
- Set permissions to 777 and still get 403 and no index listing
- if I try to access a bogus file in the same directory, I get a 404
- I create a hardlink to the file and the hardlink doesn't show up in index and I can't access it
- I create a copy of the file and it shows up in the listing and I can access it
- I move the original to .bak and move the copy to the same file name as the original and I can still access the copy but not the original
- I try to su - apache to head the original and I am able to
- stat seems to show everything being the same between the two except the time and inode values
- access_log and error_log shows the correct file is being accessed and I'm getting a 403 in both    [Tue Apr 22 14:27:14 2014] [error] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] (13) Permission denied: access to /PATH/ACE+TAO-6.2.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm denied

Is there anything anyone else can think of that I should try to explain what is going on here? I'm inclined to think it's an httpd issue since I can cp, stat, and head the file without issues. But I don't know how to go about testing it.

```
 $ getfacl ACE+TAO-6.2.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm 
 # file: ACE+TAO-6.2.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm 
 # owner: root 
 # group: root 
 user::rw- 
 group::r-- 
 other::r--

 $ ls -lZ ACE+TAO-6.2.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
 -rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 ACE+TAO-6.2.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: You appear to have [obfuscated too much](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632). Please check `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for related entries, and post your [basic system information](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6074/126632). See also [How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/126632).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `restorecon ACE+TAO-6.2.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm`; that `admin_home_t` shouldn't be on something in your web root.